# How to do Pandas Styling in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, styling, pandas-styles

I can't visualize data frames with Styles in PyCharm. I'm using the following user guide:
http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/style.html

I only get a Pandas styler object (`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler`)

I'm using `PyCharm 2018.3.7` and `Pandas 0.25`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

df.style
```

I would like to generate some data frames with styles e.g. color-coded cells, conditional formatting...etc.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you tried in jupyter Notebook ? that reference url used the jupyter not pycharm i don't think we can do styling in pycharm

Comment: Yes, I have, and it works perfectly there. I know I could switch IDEs, but if possible, I'd like to make it work in PyCharm. Thanks!

Comment: As jupyter notebook is using HTML, maybe by generating the html file through pycharm you can get it but it is probably gonna be quite fastidious

Comment: Thank you for the inputs so far! I'm not an engineer, actually I'm a data scientist, so I probably miss a lot of details. Could you explain why PyCharm can't do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Pandas styler generates HTML as string when you execute df.style.render().

A web browser interprets HTML and displays it in the browser.

Pycharm is not a webbrowser - it does not parse and display HTML.

Jupyter Notebook is an application written in python that uses a web browser. It provides a bridge between python and the web browser which is why you can create a pandas styler object and then see the results as rendered HTML because it has both functionalities.

You cant do this in Pycharm.