# Is it possible to display pandas styles in the IPython console?

Tags: python, pandas, console, ipython, pandas-styles

Is it possible to display [pandas styles](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) in an iPython console? The following code in a Jupyter notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 5)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 1), columns=list('B'))],
               axis=1)
df.style.format({'B': "{:.2%}"})
```

correctly produces

[image]

In the console I only get

```
In [294]: df.style.format({'B': "{:.2%}"})
Out[294]: <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x22f3f4fe780>
```

Is it possible to achieve a similar result here, or is the style engine dependent on an html frontend?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the styler really requires an html frontend, like jupyter, even if it only formats numbers (and not fonts or colors).

See e.g. here [Using Pandas Styler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268630/using-pandas-styler).

In order to convert a column to a specific format, one should use the `.map` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 5, 5)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 1), columns=list('B'))],
               axis=1)

df['C']=df['B'].map("{:.2%}".format)

print(df, end='\n\n')
print(df.dtypes)

     A         B         C
0  1.0  1.329212   132.92%
1  2.0 -0.770033   -77.00%
2  3.0 -0.316280   -31.63%
3  4.0 -0.990810   -99.08%
4  5.0 -1.070816  -107.08%

A    float64
B    float64
C     object
dtype: object
```

The drawback is, that df['C'] is not a number anymore, so you cannot properly sort the dataframe anymore.

Comment: as I found out today here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78077610/7237062 you can use df.style without a front-end. But you won't get any fancy prints. However, an interactive console styler adapter would be an interesting to experiment with packages like colorama (obviously it would be fairly limited compared to HTML, excel etc.)