# Styling negative numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe that I am exporting to Excel. I would also like to style it before the export.

I have this code which changes the background color and text color and works fine, but I would like to add to it:

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'black',
                           'color': 'lawngreen',
                           'border-color': 'white'}).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=rowPos, float_format = "%0.5f")
```

I need columns with strings and dates to have a white text color, and then positive numbers to be green and negative numbers to be red. I pulled these styles directly from pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/user_guide/style.html) on styling since I have never used it before, and am unsure how to achieve these results.

Lets say my dataframe looks like this:

```
StartDate   ExpiryDate  Commodity   Quantity  Price   Total
---------   ----------  ----------  -------   -----   -----
02/28/2024  12/28/2024  HO          10000     -3.89   -38900
02/28/2024  12/28/2024  WPI         10000      4.20    42000
```

how could I achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd break it down into three steps (*see the comments* `#`) :

```
st = (
    df.style
    # 1-applying the default styles
    .set_properties(**default_css)
    # 2-formatting the numeric columns
    .apply(
        lambda df_: df_.select_dtypes("number")
        .lt(0).replace({True: tc(neg), False: tc(pos)}),
        axis=None,
    )
    .format(precision=2) # this one is optional
    # 3-formatting the string-like dates and strings
    .map(lambda v: tc(obj) if isinstance(v, str) else "")
)

# st.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False) # uncomment to make an Excel
```

Output :

[image]

Used CSS :

```
default_css = {
    "background-color": "black",
    "border": "1px solid white",
}

tc = "color: {}".format # css text color
obj, pos, neg = "white", "lawngreen", "red"
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! Is it possible to select specific columns aside from using datatypes? for instance since quantity isn't really a value i want green or red but rather blue could that be handled?

Comment: Yes I'll be happy to update the answer but you need to be sure (*at this point*) and precise about the all styles you need to apply, in order to avoid moving targets.

Comment: Yes that would be the only other style that needs to be applied

Comment: IIUC, we could do it in different ways and [here](https://pastebin.com/BbBryUg2) is one possible one, which gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIEwp.png).

Comment: yup thats perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is written in plain text in the pandas documentation link you've given yourself !

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/user_guide/style.html

## TL/DR

Full solution (adapted pandas exemple) :

[image]
[image]

tested with :

```
python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17)
ipython==8.22.1
numpy == 1.26.4
pandas == 2.2.1
openpyxl == 3.1.2
jinja2 == 3.1.3
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559078/generating-random-dates-within-a-given-range-in-pandas
def random_dates(start, end, n=10):
    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9
    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

def color_rules(val):
    if isinstance(val, (float, int)):
        color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'green'
        return f"color: {color}" # to adapt. background color could be managed too
    elif isinstance(val, (pd.Timestamp, str)):
        return "color: orange" # to adapt. background color could be managed too
    else:
        return "color: grey" 


# 
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')

df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(random_dates(start, end))

df.style.applymap(color_rules).to_excel(Path().cwd() / "test.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1', float_format = "%0.5f")
```

For further tuning, you have to chain every logic needed

```
d.style.applymap(logic1).applymap(logic2). ... .to_excel( etc.)
```

## Some context (quoting pandas doc)

> Let’s write a simple style function that will color negative numbers red and positive numbers black.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

def color_negative_red(val):
    """
    Takes a scalar and returns a string with
    the css property `'color: red'` for negative
    strings, black otherwise.
    """
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

s = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)
```

> Notice the similarity with the standard df.applymap, which operates on DataFrames elementwise. We want you to be able to reuse your existing knowledge of how to interact with DataFrames.

> Notice also that our function returned a string containing the CSS attribute and value, separated by a colon just like in a  tag. This will be a common theme.

also from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/user_guide/style.html#Building-Styles-Summary

> Style functions should return strings with one or more CSS attribute: value delimited by semicolons. Use
>
> `Styler.applymap(func)` for elementwise styles
>
> `Styler.apply(func, axis=0)` for columnwise styles
>
> `Styler.apply(func, axis=1)` for rowwise styles
>
> `Styler.apply(func, axis=None)` for tablewise styles
>
> And crucially the input and output shapes of func must match. If x is the input then func(x).shape == x.shape.

Based on all the elements, it should be fairly simple to implement your own logic for positive<->green/ negative<->red color in a Jupyter notebook.

Excel-wise the doc states:

> Export to Excel
> New in version 0.20.0
>
> Experimental: This is a new feature and still under development. We’ll be adding features and possibly making breaking changes in future releases. We’d love to hear your feedback

*Notice that the documentation also allows gradient coloring and more.*

Comment: NB: I only used ipython console (no jupyter), and found out that jinja2 was necessary for proper usage of `df.style`

Comment: I saw that, but applying it to the code I have provided is where I am struggling to find a solution

Comment: added something to handle dates, see corrected answer

Comment: if i try to include background color like this: f"background-color: black, color: {color}" it does not work